# confused about keys and using it with multiple computers

Tags: server, ssh, encryption, root

well I am confused about the keys and security. Ive tried searching for a answer, but I just wind up more confused

Anyhow, my linux box, called skyline, has ssh enabled and I also edited the `sshd_config`

```
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

thats is my current config

anyhow, i am trying to ssh using putty from a windows machines and keeps saying "no supported authentication available server sent pub key" (keep in mind I also want to access skyline from multiple computers using key encryption

so what exactly am I supposed to do? do i create a key in linux and paste it to putty? Also, I want to be able to access skyline, my linux computer, from multiple computers, so how do I go about creating keys and where to place them? thank you!

I just get confused because there are multiple key folders like this

```
ssh_host_dsa_key........
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub..........
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.............
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub...........
ssh_host_ed25519_key..........
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub...........
ssh_host_rsa_key.........
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub............
```

unclear which one has the  correct key

Answer (score 1):

You use putty gen to generate a key, then on the ssh computer you set the pubkey to work with the  ssh server.

If you need more guidance may I recommend reading this site:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
Thanks hope this helps!

Comment: hi thanks i know how to generate keys, but where do i place these keys is where I need help in. Also, what if I want to access linux with multiple computers?

Comment: this link should help explain how to do it! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2